# How to Create a Pandas Index Faster?

Tags: python, performance, pandas

Why is the following snippet performing so badly:

```python
import numpy
import pandas

time = numpy.array(range(0, 1000000, 10), dtype = numpy.uint32)
index = [ pandas.Timedelta(str(t) + 'ms') for t in time ]
```

It takes approximately a second and a half on a decent desktop and we are talking only a million of `pandas.Timedelta`. Any ideas how to rewrite the last line?

Comment: What about `pd.to_timedelta(time, unit='ms')` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need [TimedeltaIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#timedeltaindex) is possible use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) or [`TimedeltaIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.TimedeltaIndex.html):

```
index = pd.to_timedelta(time, unit='ms')
```

Or:

```
index = pd.TimedeltaIndex(time, unit='ms')
```

Comment: This improves the performance 5 times. You are right. I should use `TimeDeltaIndex` instead of arrays of `TimeDelta'. Thanks. I will accept the answer in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [**`pd.timedelta_range`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.timedelta_range.html)

```
index = pd.timedelta_range(0, periods=10000, freq='10ms')
```